# @EnvironmentObject conforming to protocol: Xcode not compiling

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm playing with SwiftUI and would like to abstract an `@EnvironmentObject`. The goal is to switch from a production `BindableObject` to a fake one (testing / working local ...)

First I just declared a protocol:

```
protocol FetcherInterface: BindableObject {
    associatedtype T
    var didChange: PassthroughSubject<[T], Never> { get set }
    var values: [T] { get set }
}
```

Then I can wrote a network root class conforming to `FetcherInterface`:

```
open class NetworkFetcher<T: Decodable>: FetcherInterface {

    public var didChange = PassthroughSubject<[T], Never>()
    internal var values: [T] = [T]() {
        didSet {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                dump("did set network values \(self.values)")
                self.didChange.send(self.values)
            }
        }
    }

    internal func loadAsync(values: [T]) {
        DispatchQueue.global().asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
            self.values = values
        }
    }
}
```

I can now have a child class like this one:

```
final class PlacesNetworkFetcher: NetworkFetcher<Place>, PlacesQueryInterface {

    func loadPlacesFromCountryCode(_ countryCode: String) {
        self.loadAsync(values: [Place(id: UUID(), name: "London")])
    }
}
```

with `PlacesQueryInterface`:

```
protocol PlacesQueryInterface {
    func loadPlacesFromCountryCode(_ countryCode: String)
}
extension PlacesQueryInterface where Self: FetcherInterface {}
```

When I want to use all of this in my `ContentView.swift` Xcode never end compilation.
Looks like environment object is causing this:

`@EnvironmentObject var placesQueryInterface: PlacesQueryInterface`

Do you have an idea why ?

**edit:** I put a [project skeleton](https://github.com/abiaad/FakeServicePOC-swiftUI) if you want to test

Comment: On my machine it never even finishes indexing. Clearly this makes the compiler / indexer very unhappy. File a bug report with Apple immediately, please.

Comment: thanks @matt I just did it.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I wanted to apply it to the same case (testing/working)

Answer (score 0):

With beta 3, the never ending compilation has been fixed, however, it returns immediately with an error. Now you can see what your real problem is:

[image]

```
@EnvironmentObject var placesQueryInterface: (FetcherInterface & PlacesQueryInterface)
```

Comment: I don't now. But wrappedValue wasn't there in beta2. It is a new addition, but its description is identical to value. They're probably both the same thing.

Comment: Could you please add a little more explanation? I don't understand the error. Also, there is no explanation around the code snippet. Is it correct or not?